# Percentage calculation

Tags: solidity, tokens

I'm currently learning how to write smart contracts.
While studying some code, I came across this line: ‭

```
uint256 a = value.ceil(basePercent);
```

(with: uint256 public basePercent = 100;)

Then one calculates 1% of the value with:

```
 uint256 onePercent = a.mul(basePercent).div(10000);
```

But why was the first line of code necessary or what is it doing?

Comment: where is the variable a used?

Comment: sorry forgot to change. I'll edit it

Comment: I agree that the `ceil` line doesn't make any sense it the given context (and on a fixed-point infrastructure such as that of Solidity in general (unless this function took two inputs - numerator an denominator, or numerator and resolution)). Perhaps you wold care to share the source of this code...

Comment: this function has just 1 input (value) and returns onePercent (of the value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check with the code below that this line:

```
uint256 roundValue = SafeMath.ceil(_value, basePercent);
```

If your value `_value` is higher than `basePercent`, `roundValue` will be the number rounded on the hundred, otherwise the `_value` will be `basePercent` always.

Example: `input = 1`--> `roundValue = 100`

Example: `input = 4111`--> `roundValue = 4200`

---

Code:

Supposing a `SafeMath library` like the following:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

library SafeMath {
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(c / a == b);
    return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }

    function ceil(uint256 a, uint256 m) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = add(a,m);
        uint256 d = sub(c,1);
        return mul(div(d,m),m);
    }
}
```

And the `onePercent` function:

```
import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract Percentage{
    
    uint256 public basePercent = 100;

    function onePercent(uint256 _value) public view returns (uint256)  {
        uint256 roundValue = SafeMath.ceil(_value, basePercent);
        uint256 onePercent = SafeMath.div(SafeMath.mul(roundValue, basePercent), 10000);
        return onePercent;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! So the advantage of getting roundValue is that if the token has 0 decimals you get results approximating 1% of the initial value?

Comment: That's what I suppose.